# How to copy the default NavigationBar background image in iOS11?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The NavigationBar in iOS11 has a nice blur to it. I'm trying to replicate this to another image.

The following will set the NavigationBar with the default values (that include the blur):

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
```

I'm simply trying to copy the background to a new image to match the look but the following does not work:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundImage(for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I never could figure this out but I was able to solve it by using a blank UIToolbar where I needed to replicate the navBar background.

In my case I was trying to set the statusBar to have the same background and the navigationBar.

```
statusBarView = UIToolbar()
```

To set it with the default background:

```
self.statusBarView.setBackgroundImage(nil, forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

And to make it transparent:

```
self.statusBarView.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```